# Complete the tonal words

Tags: wordplay, word-property

***A small introduction:***
*This could have been a "What is a ??? Word™" question, but I decided to give it a little twist. The first part is simply about finding out what makes the short words Tonal (although I decided later that "Notable" might be an even better description, so wherever you read "Tonal" you may also read "Notable"). The poem will help you as you go along.*

> Complete all tonal words below,
>   List their options in a row.
>   Numbers for letters is what you need,
>   They indicate what you should read.
>   Just take these, strike out the rest,
>   Now you have fulfilled your quest.

[image]

**N.B.: All tonal words can be found in [this](http://www.dictionary.com/) English dictionary.**

P.S.: Here is a text version of the picture above:

```
TONAL -> LUNATIC  
LEACH -> SARCASM  
HEAP  -> SASHIMI  
ROLL  -> PLATEAU  
VERY  -> COMPLEX  
RISKY -> COMPLEX  
HOST  -> THOUGHT  
READ  -> ATTEMPT  
MEND  -> REVISIT  
ARROW -> FORTIFY  
LIGHT -> WONDERS  
GO    -> DYNASTY  
LOVE  -> OUTDRAW  
RACE  -> PONTIFF  
OLD   -> COUTURE  
OWN   -> ANALYZE  
LONG  -> VOUCHER  
ROOM  -> ENCRYPT  
STRAY -> HUNDRED  
LASH  -> SPECIES  
RANK  -> SANDBOX  
ROUND -> NOTABLE
```

**Hint:**

> Finding out what makes the shorter words tonal/notable is key.

**Hint 2:**

> The tonal/notable property is related to the fact that these words are incomplete.

Comment: Does each pair gives a single word or a part of word? You can choose not to answer.

Comment: @Techidiot: The pairs don't necessarily lead to single words.

Comment: To be clear, are the short words Tonal Words and the longer 7-letter ones Notable Words?

Comment: No, the short words are both Tonal and Notable. I called them "Tonal" first but then decided that "Notable" might be a better description, but I didn't want to change the title, because I thought it might be confusing. I'll edit the post a bit.

Comment: I'd like to say that this is indeed *much* better constructed than the "What is a ??? Word™" series, and in particular I liked the initial confirmation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

tonal - there is only ATONAL = A so i pick only 1st from word below = L
leach - there is only BLEACH = B so i pick only 2nd from word below = A
…
LASTLET(TE)(RS)(OF)(WOR)(DS)(TW)(OF)(OURE)(LE)(VE)(NT)(HR)(EE)(ANDO)(NE)

"last letters of words two four eleven three and one"

Honestly i think i made some new words and forgot some. My english is not that good, but u got an idea.
Basically u have for example word ROUND - so u try to find A-round, B-round, C-round, etc, but u choose only existing ones - like AROUND and GROUND, that's A and G = 1st and 7th letter in word below = (N and E)

and for answer:

sarcasM
plateaU
wonderS
sashimI
lunatiC
 - > MUSIC

Comment: You've inserted an extra letter and you're missing FLONG, but that looks mostly right. Almost there :)

Answer (score 4):

The answer is

> Music

And the method is

> Create a list of words out of the given first words by way of prepending a musical note (A-G), then use the prepended notes to select letters out of the second word.

This yields the message

> "Last Letter of words two, four, eleven, three, and one" which yields the answer.

My work is as follows, uglified.

> ```
>  Atonal                        L
>  Bleach                        A
>  Cheap                         S
>  Droll                         T
>
>  Every                         L
>  Frisky                        E
>  Ghost                         T
>  Bread (Dread)                 T/E
>  Amend                         R
>
>  Barrow (Carrow)               O/F
>  Alight (Blight) (Flight)      W/O/R
>  Ago (Ego)                     D/S
>
>  Clove (Glove)                 T/W
>  Brace (Grace)                 O/F
>  Bold (Cold) (Fold) (Gold)     O/U/R/E
>  Down (Gown)                   L/E
>  Along (Flong)                 V/E
>  Broom (Groom)                 N/T
>  Astray  (Estray)              H/R
>  Clash (Flash)                 E/E
>  Brank? (Crank) (Drank) (Frank)A/N/D/O
>  Around (Ground)               N/E
> ```